# How do i get the date that is 15 days more from the date selected in datepicker?

Tags: jquery, html

I picked this code from jQuery forum.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#selectedDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(_date) {
            var myDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            console.log(myDate);
            myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 15);
            $('#retrieveDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-dd-mm', myDate));
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Selected Date in Datepicker</label>
    <input type="text" name="selected_date" class="form-control datepicker"
           id="selectedDate">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Retrieve Date</label>
    <input type="text" id="retrieveDate" name="retrieve_date"
           class="form-control">
</div>
```

When I select the date in first input, the second input must be automatically filled with the date that is 15 days more from the selected date in the datepicker.

Comment: Inputs usually have values, can you try changing `$('#retrieveDate').text(..)`  to `$('#retrieveDate').val(...)`?

Comment: just use .val(..) instead of .text(...) 
.val is used for inputfields. text is used for non inputfields

Comment: [jQuery UI's Datepicker component documentation shows it has a `setDate` function for this purpose](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)...

Comment: Thanks It worked. I had tried using .val() but don't why it didn't work and now it is working. Thank you all.

Comment: It looks like there are 2 date formats `'yy-mm-dd'` and `'yy-dd-mm'`, so could be that val is not working for every date this way. I would give the method mentioned by @HereticMonkey a try: `$('#retrieveDate').datepicker('setDate', myDate);` (This way you only have one place for your date format and aren't at risk to mix something up. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line:

```
$('#retrieveDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-dd-mm', myDate));
```

by this: to add text by jQuery you should use val()

```
$('#retrieveDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-dd-mm', myDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is your declaration of 'myDate' as var and then trying to write it as a text. Try converting myDate to a String after you add 15 days.